# Android native browser navigation bar

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, browser, navigationbar

I'm working on a responsive website and want to make an overlay menu like on play.google.com.
My layer get's dynamicaly the height of the window to fill the screen from top to bottom and get's "position:fixed" to stay where it is.

I do "window.scroll(0,100)" to vanish the navigation bar. But when I try to scroll inside my menu by touch the whole page scrools up and shows the navition bar again. Then it's no longer possible to scroll the page. The result of this behavior is, that man menu is now to long and the bottom of the menu is no longer visible on the page.

On the google play website they used something that the navigation bar never vanishes and I think this could help to avoid my problem also, but I haven't found out how to do that, yet.

I hope someone of you has some experiance in that.

thanks in advance 
Frank